# Combining If and Right function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m working on some addresses and want to clean up a bit. My question is how to combine if and right. If a cell contains word Horoo, delete all the words before and with Horoo. If a word is not present delete the word Sbd. 
Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: hello - can you post an example for us to understand what you try to achieve?  Furthermore, have you tried something this far ?

Comment: SBD 6 horoo 30-31. SBD Mart building. SBD 5 Horoo 441 etc. all of them start with SBD, but some of them don’t have word horoo. Want to post pictures but limit is 2mb

Answer (score 2):

A few assumptions I used for the below formula:

1. Horoo can appear in upper or lower case
2. Horoo can appear in any location in the address
3. SBD always appears at the beginning of the address with a space afterwards
4. When we want to remove the SBD we only want to remove the first 4 characters, not anywhere in the address

If cell A1 has Horoo we need the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("horoo",A1)-5)
```

If cell A1 doesn't have Horoo we need the following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4)
```

To combine them in a way that if the first formula fails then we have the second formula work:

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("horoo",A1)-5),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-4))
```

Comment: Since `SEARCH` is case-insensitive, you could use that instead of `FIND` and `LOWER`.  And if all start with `SBD` (as the OP noted in his comment), you could just skip the first four characters with `MID`. And when using `SUBSTITUTE` you also need to consider if the OP wants `SBD` removed if it appears other than at the start of the string.

Comment: Good points @RonRosenfeld! Editing the answer to these functions (although I prefer `RIGHT` to `MID`)

Comment: Great! happy we could help @Cacral :) don't forget to mark it as the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove the word "Horoo" from cell A1, you can use following formula:

```
=RIGHT(A1;LENGTH(A1)-Find("Horoo";A1)-LENGTH("Horoo"))
```

What does all this mean?

```
Find("Horoo";A1) looks for the word and gives its location (of the first letter).
Length("Horoo") : you also need to remove the whole word (not only the first letter)
```

As for the "SBD" part of the question, you might use an `=IFERROR()` formula for determining what to do.

Comment: This will return an error if `horoo` is not present, and using `FIND` will make the formula case-sensitive.  Also, you can use `SUBSTITUTE` to remove `SBD`

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: you're right. Therefore I've replaced `IF` by `IFERROR` to catch this case.